# jQuery Passing $(this) to a Function

Tags: jquery, this, parameter-passing

I have lines of code like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().each(function(){
    // do something
});
```

It works well. But I need to run these lines multiple times.
So I have created a function and pass $(this) parameter to a function:

```
myFunc( $(this) );

function myFunc(thisObj) {
    thisObj.parent().parent().children().each(function(){
        // do something
    });
}
```

But in this way, It didn't work.

Comment: What if you use "this" instead of "$(this)" as parameter?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as written, so I suggest it's an error somewhere else. What do you mean by, "It didn't work"?

Comment: I have use "this", but It doesn't work either. When I see $this and thisObj in Firebug it shows this: {$this = input.focus} but {thisObj = [input.focus]} ... Is there any difference?

Comment: @Natasha did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 84):

you can check this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/38/

```js
$("#f").click(function() {
  myFunc($(this));
})

function myFunc(thisObj) {
  thisObj.parent().parent().children().each(function() {
    alert("childs")
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="wordlist">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b">
    <div id="e"></div>
    <div id="f">child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 18):

jQuery will automatically invoke your function with the proper context set.

```
$('#button').on('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var that = $(this);
    console.log(that);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work in [no-conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) (i.e. out of global scope), one of the possibilities is:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
    $('#button').on('click', myFunction);
}(jQuery));

// or
jQuery('#button').on('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var that = jQuery(this);
    console.log(that);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the id to the function.  With your loop inside the function.

```
myFunc(this.id);

function myFunc(thisid) {
    $("#" + thisid).parent().parent().children().each(function(){
        // do something
    });
}
```

I would normally do the loop outside the function like below:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().each(function(){
    myFunc(this.id)
});

function myFunc(thisid) {

    // do something example
   $("#" + thisid).html("Yay, i changed the html for element: " + thisid);
}
```