# simplify functions jquery

Tags: function, var, light, simplify

I have these "functions" that are repeated in the block for the various elements.
How can I simplify using "var"?

thank you : )

For example:

```
$('#test1').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $(this).addClass("here");
    $(this).prevAll().removeClass("here");
    $(this).prev().prev().addClass("here_pre");
    $(this).next().next().addClass("here_pre");
  },
});
```

I would like to arrive at a solution such as this:

```
var active_here = $(this).addClass("here"),
                  $(this).prevAll().removeClass("here"),
                  $(this).prev().prev().addClass("here_pre"),
                  $(this).next().next().addClass("here_pre");
```

And finally recall something like this:

```
$('#test1').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
  active_here;
  },
});

$('#test2').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
  active_here;
  },
});

etc... etc... etc...
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write your own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript variable function (or can be declared as normal function either):

```
var active_here = function($elem){
    $elem.addClass("here");
    $elem.prevAll().removeClass("here");
    $elem.prev().prev().addClass("here_pre");
    $elem.next().next().addClass("here_pre");
}
```

Calling:

```
$('#test1').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    active_here($(this));
  },
});

$('#test2').waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    active_here($(this));
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a function and then just call the function inside of your function?

```
function active_here(this) {
      //code here..
}
```

Comment: At the point he'd be calling it, he is in the function that took direction as a parameter.  Is "this" still the element by then? I'd think it isn't, but could be wrong.

Comment: Yes he can here is a link to another thread with the same question ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767593/jquery-passing-this-to-a-function

Comment: Not sure if we are talking apples to apples. In that example, the person explicitly passes "this" as the parameter to the callback function. In this question, his function has the need for a parameter of "direction".